# To integrate scala into java using maven, how do compare available plugins?

Tags: java, scala, maven

Trying to integrate scala into a Java project.
After a Google query, I am given the choice between

[org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-with-maven.html)

and the more recent

[net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin](http://fruzenshtein.com/scala-in-java-maven-project/)

which one to use in what case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have to support older maven versions than 3.0 or have any other legacy reasons for using the maven-scala-plugin (last release in 2011), you should go for the net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin.

It's the same plugin, but it was renamed for maven naming policy reasons. There's a section about this in the [official scala documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-with-maven.html#the-scala-maven-plugin).

Comment: Why ? isn't   org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin the official implementation ?

Comment: I updated my answer and added a link to the official scala doc.

Comment: the fact net.alchim31 is mentioned in the official scala documentation makes it clearly official.